# How to run a python script stored in singularity container?

Tags: python, singularity-container

I'm currently engaged in a project that involves deploying the application within a Singularity container environment. The application is coded in python. I have setup a singularity container sandbox and installed all the dependencies of the project within it. The container works fine in an interactive mode and I can execute my app by binding the the directory where it's stored on my local machine.
My aim is to combine the container and the application into a unified entity. Users should have the ability to execute the application just by directly launching the singularity container. The objective is to offer users solely the singularity container, without any additional requirements.

## What I have tried--

I attempted to integrate a basic python script(a "hello world" program). The script is stored in the /opt/conda/bin folder inside sandbox. After making the file executable and modifying the "singularity" executable file, I accessed the container using the "--writable" mode and successfully executed the "singularity" executable. However, upon running it from outside the container on my local machine, I encountered an error stating "file not found."

```
saksham@init:~/Desktop/rha$ sudo singularity shell --writable update2_pytorch
WARNING: Skipping mount /home/saksham/Desktop/rha [cwd]: /home/saksham/Desktop/rha doesn't exist in container
Singularity> ../singularity 
Hello World 2
Singularity> exit
saksham@init:~/Desktop/rha$ update2_pytorch/singularity 
update2_pytorch/singularity: 4: test.py: not found
saksham@init:~/Desktop/rha$
```

Please ignore the mistakes. I'm new to singularity.

Thank you!!

Comment: Have you tried building it as an image file (instead of sandbox) and including `python /opt/conda/bin/test.py` in the `%runscript` section?

Comment: Yes, this worked. Thanks a lot!
Running sandbox as a whole also works.